# ошибка "string indicies must be integers" при попытке итерации списка словарей по результату input

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, type-error

Суть задачи: у меня есть пополняемый список словарей (коллекция фильмов), в котором нужно реализовать функцию поиска, взяв от пользователя данные (использую input).

Проблема: при попытке итерации по списку словарей с использованием данных, принятых от пользователя, Python 3.7 говорит, что "TypeError: string indicies must be integers".

Вопросы: 1) почему выдаётся ошибка? 2) Как принять данные (название фильма) от пользователя и найти соответствие ему в списке словарей?

Подозреваю, что интерпретатору не нравится либо то, что результатом input является строка, и такой тип данных он не может использовать для итерации, либо то, что мои словари находятся в списке, и я неправильно осуществляю итерацию именно по **списку** словарей.

Вот код (он ещё в процессе создания и наверняка вообще неоптимизированный, "непитонный" и с кучей других ошибок, но прошу сильно не ругать, - я "пытаюсь программировать" всего три недели).

За помощь и конструктивную критику большое спасибо!

```py
# Movie Library v.1.0

movie_library = []

# Menu
ask_add_find = input("Do you want to find or add a movie, or view your collection? (add/find/view) ")


def search_library(search_title):
    for m in movie_library:
        if m['title'] == search_title:
            return m


while ask_add_find:
    if ask_add_find == "add":
        add_title = input("Movie title: ")
        add_year = input("Release year: ")
        add_dir = input("Director: ")
        add_genre = input("Genre: ")
        movie_library = dict(title=add_title, year=add_year, director=add_dir, genre=add_genre)
        print("Thanks. Your movie library has been updated.")
        print(movie_library)
        ask_add_find = input("Do you want to find or add a movie, or view your collection? (add/find/view) ")
    elif ask_add_find == "find":
        search_title = input("Search movie by name (e.g., 'Matrix'): ")
        search_library(movie_library)
    elif ask_add_find == "view":
        print(movie_library)
        ask_add_find = input("Do you want to find or add a movie, or view your collection? (add/find/view) ")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect input. Please choose again.")
        ask_add_find = input("Do you want to find or add a movie, or view your collection? (add/find/view) ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле проблема в том, что в кейсе `ask_and_find` вы переопределяете `movie_library` (которая была листом) в словарь. Вот и получается, что в функцию вы передаете *измененную* глобальную `movie_library`, которая теперь является словарем, а не листом.

Чтобы все было совсем хорошо, нужно заменить строчку

```
movie_library = dict(title=add_title, year=add_year, director=add_dir, genre=add_genre)
```

На

```
movie_library.append(dict(title=add_title, year=add_year, director=add_dir, genre=add_genre))
```

Без этого получается, что вы итерируетесь по элементам словаря, а потом берете элемент по индексу `'title'`.

Ну и было бы в целом хорошо, если бы кейсы `find` и `view` при вызове сообщали, если в коллекции еще ничего нет.

P.S Чтобы не попадать в такие ситуации, можно использовать какой-нибудь линтер и ["подсказки типов"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Comment: Отлично, большое спасибо за помощь! Проблема решена! Ходил вокруг да около, о сути проблемы догадался правильно но, видимо, из-за пока  трудного чтения кода и расставления связей между  частями не нашёл решения.
Теперь код, правда, не хочет использовать функцию, но вышел из ситуации, скопировав тело функции прямо в тело условия elif: 

'    
elif ask_add_find == "find":
search_title = input("Search movie by name (e.g., 'Matrix'): ")
    for m in movie_library:
        if m['title'] == search_title:
            print(m)
'

А потом узнал о функции next и ещё укоротил с помощью неё :)

Comment: @АлександрЛемонов рад, что вы нашли что-то полезное для себя :)
Кстати есть [трюк со словарем](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python), имитирующий `switch-case` других языков. Вдруг вам пригодится)